# Bash: number of seconds till midnight of current day

Tags: bash, time, date-time

How do I find the **number of seconds till midnight** of current day?

Comment: Doens't that rather belong to stackoverflow?

Comment: @Benoit : I considered that, but decided against because I thought that this would be scripting, not programming.

Comment: Warning: you are trying to do interval arithmetic with absolute times of day. Think carefully about what happens around DST transitions.

Comment: @Phil : Yup, a solution which takes DST (and other corner cases) would be ideal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about:

```
echo $(($(date -d "$(date +00:00-24:00)" +%s)-$(date +%s)))
```

Comment: What does `date +00:00-24:00` do?

Comment: Yeah, the man page doesn't give any clues.

Comment: This one is definitely giving me the wrong answer.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a version of date that supports it:

```
echo $(($(date -d 23:59:59 +%s) - $(date +%s) + 1))
```

or

```
echo $(($(date -d 'tomorrow 00:00:00' +%s) - $(date +%s)))
```

Comment: first one seems better from a computational efficiency perspective

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution which works always try this:

```
$((`date +%s` % 86400 + $OFFSET ))
```

The `$OFFSET` should be the difference in seconds between the local timezone and UTC.

Comment: Does this work at the transition of winter/summer time (... wasting time)?